Config v2ray or xray Vless Config Tester
how to check config vless is working in python and check connection internet is connected after vless connected
i try this code :
I wrote the code in a concise way, my goal is to first connect the wils file first and then check if the internet access is established or not.
import base64
import json
import subprocess
import speedtest
from subprocess import check_output
import os
import time
def start_v2ray(file_name: str):
    
      file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('config',file_name))
      process = subprocess.Popen(f'Xray/xray.exe run -config="{file_name}"', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      
      time.sleep(1.5)

      was_success = process.poll() is None and process.returncode is None
      print(f"xray.exe executed success: {was_success}")
      if was_success:
          ....test ping after that,but not working
          process.kill()
          return True
      else:
          return None





config_path = 'vless.json' 
if start_v2ray(config_path):
    print("Connected to VLESS server.")
else:
    print("Failed to connect to VLESS server.")


I really needed such a project thanks
But there is a problem
xray.exe executed success: False
Failed to connect to VLESS server.
i use xray.exe from v2rayN files but not working

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
